# Logistic Regression with categorically and Continuous independent variables. ROC Curve and confusion matrix

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to perform a logistic regression using the below syntax,

```
logregmodel <- glm(Y ~., data = quant, family = binomial() )
```

I have 15 categorical variables and 30 Continuous variables.By using the above syntax I am not able to define what are the continuous and categorically variables.Typing them manually will take a lot of time.Also I want to add the ROC Curve and confusion matrix to the output.Please help.

Comment: You can use e.g. `sapply(quant, is.numeric)` or `sapply(quant, class)` to check the variable types, and `quantsub <- subset(quant, ...)` to build a subset with the vars that you want to embed in your first model.

Answer (score 1):

If in `quant`, the categorical variables are non-numeric, `glm` will process them correctly as categorical variables.

To get the confusion matrix, use the `predict` function:

```
# This will give you probabilities.
fitted <- predict(logregmodel, quant, type="response")

# Use a cut point to divide into classes
cutpoint <- 0.5
estimated.class <- ifelse(fitted > cutpoint, 'Class 1', 'Class 2')

# Calculate the confusion matrix
table(estimated.class, actual.class)
```

You can use the **ROCR** package to get the ROC curve.  [Here is a good explination](http://www.r-bloggers.com/sab-r-metrics-logistic-regression/).  You'll have to scroll down a bit for the ROC curve part but the whole thing is imformative.

The **ROCR** package (specifically the `prediction` function) can also be used to get the confusion matrix.

I would just note that the ROC curve and measures of model performance, such as sensitivity or specificity, will be biased if they are calculated from the predicted responses derived from the same data set that was used to fit the model.

Comment: Thanks christopher and luke for your guidance.Its very informative and helpful